# asp membership roles issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm having an issue when trying to add users to roles using the Default Membership Provider. 
I have the asp.net schema installed on my database and am creating users which works fine and creates users in dbo.users.

`Membership.CreateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text, Email.Text, null, null, true, out createStatus);`

However when I try to add user to the role

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(newUser.UserName, "administrators");
```

It keeps return exception, inner exception is

```
{"Invalid column name 'RoleId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'UserId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'UserId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'RoleId'."}
```

Not sure why it is claiming that the columns do not exist when all of the membership tables exist in the database.

This has had me scratching my head for the past few hours...

Any ideas help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the default role provider as well?

Comment: Yes I believe so, in web.config I have

<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"
          name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

Comment: It seems to be trying to reference the columns in dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles and not dbo.UsersInRoles. Not sure why

Comment: Hmmm the correct table name starts with "aspnet_" ...  Don't all the membership tables in your DB start with that?

Comment: aspnet_ is the prefix for the sqlmembership provider which is now obsolete it should be using the tables without the prefix when using the default memebership provider